# $X$ and $Y$ are exponential variates. How do I find $P(X<Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

The lifetime of two brands of bulbs $X$ and $Y$ are exponentially distributed with the mean life of $100$ hours. Bulb $X$ is switched on $15$ hours after Bulb $Y$ has been switched on. The probability that bulb $X$ fails before Bulb $Y$ is?

The options are:

$(A). \frac{15}{100}$

$(B). \frac{1}{2}$

$(C).\frac{85}{100}$

$(D). 0$

Comment: Hint: exponential distribution is [memoryless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Memorylessness). Bulb $Y$ will not suffer under the fact that it is allready burning for $15$ hours when $X$ is switched on. Secondly you are dealing with equal distributions.

Comment: So we we'll have to find cdf? P(X<Y)?

Comment: Do we know that bulb $Y$ is still functioning the moment bulb $X$ is switched on?

Comment: It's not given in the question. But I think   it would be.

Answer (score 4):

If bulb $Y$ might fail before bulb $X$ is switched on,

\begin{align}
&\text{ probability that bulb $X$ fails before bulb } Y \\
&= P(Y \geq 15) P(X<Y-15|Y \geq 15)+P(Y < 15)(0)
\\&=P(Y \geq 15) P(X < Y) \\
&= \frac12 P(Y \geq 15)
\end{align}

If we are given that bulb $Y$ is still working when bulb $X$ is switched on 
\begin{align}
&\text{ probability that bulb $X$ fails before bulb } Y \text{ given that bulb } Y \text{ was functioning when bulb } X \text{was switched on}  \\
&=  P(X<Y-15|Y \geq 15)
\\&= P(X < Y)
\\&= \frac12
\end{align}

Comment: Actually the options (rational and including $\frac12$) indicate that the condition $Y\geq15$ is abusively not mentioned. Secondly in the title the OP asks for $P(X<Y)$. I think that must be $P(X<Y-15\mid Y\geq15)$ (as you remark).

Comment: +1, interpreting the question as asking for $P(Y>X+15 | Y>15)$ is the only way I can see to make it fit the given answers.

Comment: I still don't understand why $P(X<Y)=\frac12$ Is this a $P(X<Y)=\frac{\frac{1}{100}}{\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}}$ situation?

Comment: They are two continuous IID, hence the value is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: (Bulb X is switched on 15 hours *after* bulb Y)

You must partition on the 15 hour.    Bulb-X may fail before bulb-Y, only if bulb-Y does not fail before bulb X is switched on.  $$\mathsf P(X<Y)~=~\mathsf P(Y\geq 15)\cdot\mathsf P(X<Y\mid Y\geq 15)$$ Now, use the memoryless property to simplify.

Comment: Concerning LHS: since $X,Y$ are iid and continuous, it is immediate that $P(X<Y)=\frac12$. Concerning RHS: it seems you accidently switched $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are not iid because bulb $X$ is switched on 15 hours later.  $Y$ and $X-15$ are iid.  (But yes, I did have the switch on times mixed around)